# Cannot set Text for a button in onTimeSet

Tags: java, android, android-button, settext

Here is my code, in my ListViewAdapter. I want to show a timePicker to set time for my Adapter. But a cannot solve my onTimeSet
p is my Adapter

```
    assert btnLeft != null;

    btnLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    p.setOnHour(hourOfDay);
                    p.setOnMinutes(minute);
                   btnLeft.setText(hourOfDay + " : " + minute);
                }
           }, p.getOnHour(), p.getOnMinutes(), false);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: that piece of code is in adapter or outside adapter?

Comment: Add your adapter code here

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, [OnTimeSetListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.html) calls onTimeSet() when

> ... the user is done setting a new time and the dialog has closed.

You need to use an [OnTimeChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener.html) with the onTimeChanged() method.